# JVMTI: FollowReferences : how to skip Soft/Weak/Phantom references?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, memory-management, jvmti

I am writing a small code to detect number of objects left behind after certain actions in our tool. This uses `FollowReferences()` from JVMTI API.  This counts instances reachable by all paths. How can I skip paths that included weak/soft/phantom reference?

(`IterateThroughHeap()` counts all objects at the moment, so the number is not fully reliable.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution (for now) is to use `FindClass` for `java/lang/ref/Reference` and then tag this as to be skipped. In the callback for `FollowReference`, skip the iteration when class is marked to be skipped.

(Real solution could be to use hprof code, shipped with Sun JDK.)